# set up moodle vidtrack completion

Tags: moodle

I'm a wordpress developer, but for a customer we are gonna set up moodle courses.
Some courses are fine and are linking to other courses on other sites that tracks completion.

But on some courses we are gonna set up a youtube video with vidtrack.
This vidtrack is logging in the database mdl_youtube that the user with id something is stating the video, pausing and reached the end.

It's this END that we are interested in.
None of us has ever been using moodle so this is kinda new.

We have been checking the activity completion in the course but can't find anything that will let us use this logging to the database from vidtrack.

Is this something that we have to code on our own? And where in moodle source code do we do this?

Hope you guys understood the question.
I will answer all the questions that you have in case i left something out or are very bad at explaining the problem.

Have a nice day.

Comment: It is hard to say whether you HAVE to code smth. On StackOverflow - you code first, get stuck, demonstrate the problem to public, get help. Show what you tried, otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: Well. Now i don't want to code it myself. That is the thing. 
We want to use vidtrack and track the progress in the course. Vidtrack is set up, the movie is in place, but there is no Activity tracking that we can find for vidtrack. Just the normal activity trackings that are no use to us.

My question is if we HAVE to code a solution or if anyone here is familiar with moodle and can tell where we can set this solution up in moodle.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that seems to me without getting into coding is that, put all your files through SCROM packages in SCO and then divide them into segments.

If it is a long video, this would definitely be a good strategy because even though one cannot force students to actually see the video, at least they would be forced to wait for each segment to end and then click on the next section.

Thanks!!